# What does the PHP interpreter do at if("test")

Tags: php, if-statement

I've a small question behind a bug I found in a customers code. There is a PHP if-statement, which is true at every time. There was something like

```
if("test"){
}
```

What does the PHP interpreter exactly do? Like if "test" can be stored in the RAM or if "test" == "test"? Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Its true because its a [truthy value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), check **Comparisons of $x with PHP functions** case **$x = "php";/if($x)**.

Comment: It does the same thing it always does with an `if` - it checks whether the value of that expression is truthy or falsy

Comment: Make sense. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP interpreter will convert "test" to its boolean value (true in this case).
Following values are considered as falsy :
0, false, 0.0, -0.0, empty array, empty string "", "0", null and SimpleXML objects if created from elements without attributes.